# Internal working of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My first question is

Does SQL Server work asynchronously or synchronously?

- if it works asynchronously:
  how many inserting (or any other) asynchronous calls can be handled by SQL Server, or is it dependent on virtual memory?
- if it works synchronously:
  how many synchronous calls can be handled by SQL Server? Is there any queue maintained by SQL Server for pending requests? If yes, then how many pending request can be handled..

Comment: See the [How Batch or Task Scheduling Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189267.aspx) section here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly...

Any call to the database is synchronous: you call, you wait for a result. But asynchronous vs synchronous isn't really how RDBMS work

Going further...

The main thing for any RDBMS is concurrency. RDBMS are designed to handle 1000s of concurrent connections

You can have many overlapping and concurrent readers until the server runs out of resources.

Where you do get some concept of asynchronous vs synchronous is around writes. These are exclusive and serialised (by default) and wil blokc reader for the duration of the transation.

For resources (some generalisations here which makes them susepct :-)

- Write throughput is determined by IO bandwidth mostly and lot by code design
- Read throughout is limited by network/CPU and code design again, mostly.
- Memory shouldn't be an issue normally because cached data is shared
- In practice, poor code or design affects resource usage most except for large DBs/load

For example, poor indexing is one of the biggest killer of database performance

Comment: thankx for reply,i am not talking about number of connection connections... i am talking about number of concurrent operations on the sql server.... for example if there are 100 connections at a time , what happen is all connections submit a insert request to sql server....

Comment: Worst case, the 100 INSERTs will be synchronous, one after the other because of synchronous. If the INSERTs are distributed across a large table, then you will affect different pages and they could be run with some concurrency

Comment: so it means if there are 100 operation request to sql,but sql process one by one....plz let me know where the pending request(which are not executed yet) get stored...

Comment: @slash shogdhe: it's so quick as to be barely noticeble. But you'd need to look are the blocking info in sys.sysprocesses

Comment: just last question.. how many operation request can be handeled by sql... just the imaginary figure...

Comment: as well please suggest me any book that can help me in this

Comment: We have 50k rows per second (batched) at peak. This guys has 35k transactions per second http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/12/12/10-lessons-from-35k-tps.aspx. There is no hard upper limit